# How come the Image is not displayed on screen after I pick the Image for the phones photo gallery

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

I am able to gain access to the phones photo library using the but when I click on a image_picker import but when I choose a image it reverts to home screen and does not display the image picked

I think it may have to do with how I define the variable that will store my image file at the beginning but i am not sure.

```
File? imageFile;
```

here is my code.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
  //runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyApp> {
  /// Variables
  File? imageFile;

  /// Widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Image Picker"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: imageFile == null
              ? Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('heyheyheyheyhey');
                          _getFromGallery();
                        },
                        child: Text("PICK FROM GALLERY"),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 40.0,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _getFromCamera();
                        },
                        child: Text("PICK FROM CAMERA"),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  child: Image.file(
                    imageFile!,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
        ));
  }

  /// Get from gallery
  _getFromGallery() async {
    print('heyheyheyheyhey');
    PickedFile pickedFile = (await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    )) as PickedFile;
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
        print('heyheyheyheyhey');
      });
    }
  }

  //Get from Camera
  _getFromCamera() async {
    PickedFile pickedFile = (await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    )) as PickedFile;
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Image picker returns the future object of XFile, that was causing a problem for you.

Here is the updated code of your functions:

```
/// Get from gallery
_getFromGallery() async {
  print('heyheyheyheyhey');
  XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    maxWidth: 1800,
    maxHeight: 1800,
  );
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    setState(() {
      imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      print('heyheyheyheyhey');
    });
  }
}

//Get from Camera
_getFromCamera() async {
  XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera,
    maxWidth: 1800,
    maxHeight: 1800,
  );
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    setState(() {
      imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: o I get you, thank you